# Update field with query using longest match number

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have the following table of call_logs:

```
+------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| id         | datetime            | a_number   | b_number    |     nem      |
+------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 1262662410 | 2020-07-17 10:43:57 | 3415529238 | 12642356719 |              |
| 1262661229 | 2020-07-17 10:43:48 | 1126751251 | 12641344559 |              |
| 1262658679 | 2020-07-17 10:43:28 | 3516807236 | 16199573103 |              |
+------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

and another table of prefixes:

```
+---------+-------+-------------------+------+
| prefix  | lenght| description       | nem  |
+---------+-------+-------------------+------+
| 1907    |     4 | ALASKA            | ALAS |
| 1684    |     4 | AMERICAN SAMOA    | ASAM |
| 1264    |     4 | ANGUILLA          | AGLL |
| 1264235 |     7 | ANGUILLA - MOBILE | AGLM |
| 1264469 |     7 | ANGUILLA - MOBILE | AGLM |
| 1264476 |     7 | ANGUILLA - MOBILE | AGLM |
| 1264536 |     7 | ANGUILLA - MOBILE | AGLM |
| 1264537 |     7 | ANGUILLA - MOBILE | AGLM |
| 1264538 |     7 | ANGUILLA - MOBILE | AGLM |
| 1264539 |     7 | ANGUILLA - MOBILE | AGLM |
+---------+-------+-------------------+------+
```

What MySQL query or precedure do you recommend to update the call_logs.nem field analyzing the prefixes.prefix field that best matches (with the greatest number of digits) with the field `call_logs.b_number`.

Example:

```
+------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| id         | datetime            | a_number   | b_number    |     nem      |
+------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 1262662410 | 2020-07-17 10:43:57 | 3415529238 | 12642356719 |    AGLM      |
| 1262661229 | 2020-07-17 10:43:48 | 1126751251 | 12641344559 |    AGLL      |
+------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

call_logs is a big table, it would be good to find the most efficient method.
Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks a lot!

**CLARIFICATION:**
Both fields: `b_number`and `prefix` are VARCHAR type.
What type of UPDATE Query could be done in this case?

Comment: What are the datatypes of columns `prefix` and `b_number`?

Comment: When you come here to ask a question, you should pay attention to the comments... Not reacting to them seems to indicate you have no interest any more.

Comment: @trincot Why? The commentator answered the question regardless, so from the OP's point of view it would have been wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`. Assuming that `number` and `prefix` are of numeric datatypes:

```
update call_logs c
inner join prefixes p on (c.b_number / p.prefix) % 10 = 0
set c.mem = p.mem
where not exists (
    select 1
    from prefixes p1
    where (c.b_number / p1.prefix) % 10 = 0 and p1.length > p.length
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I apologize for the lack of precision in the description of the problem, it is my first question in English on StackOverflow.
Both `number` and `prefix` fields are of type varchar.
This is so because eventually the `number` field could contain some hexadecimal digit at the end.